# Is it impossible to see elasticbeanstalk ec2 instance setup script file and configuration file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking all day for searching elasticbeanstalk ec2 instance setup script and its configuration file. But failed to find those.

I want to see myself where eb ec2 instance stores s3 uploaded .zip files.

Investigating through some amount of time, I found **eb-engine.log (/var/logs/eb-engine.log)**, and it shows that ec2 instance unzips the file from **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle** and copies it to the **/var/app/staging**, and finally we can find those unzipped file at **/var/app/current.**

But the logs does not show us where exactly ec2 instance downloads s3 files to at the first place, and when /var/app/staging is being removed, replaced by /var/app/current.

So I want to see the ec2 instance's initial setup script, and its configuration file. But failed to find it. Where can I some see more detailed procedures?

I've also checked cloudformation, but it didn't help though.

Any ideas would really be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the CloudFormation templates as I wrote before?

Comment: @Marcin Yes I've checked it. Do you mean CloudFormation - Template?

Comment: Yes. I provided answer to your other question, but due to lack of any comments iam not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Marcin Yes. I checked your previous answer. and I am really glad you to help me. I found that Cloudformation - Template does not show where ec2 instance saves s3 files initially. But it shows the where the config path is. for example, /opt\/elasticbeanstalk\/config\/platformconfig\/packages.json, and I opened all the files giving permissions with chmod 400, but failed to find the valid information. Your answer helped me though, and if I could find your answer informative, I would have chosen your answer. Could you please narrow it down?

Comment: @Marcin Can you elaborate this?